# Trying to solve a beginner Python looping assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, while-loop

I have to make a program that asks the user for a String and then counts and prints the number of vowels in the String. The vowels that count are a, e, i, o, u, y, and the uppercase versions of these. For example, the input "ebony and ivory" would print 7. I also can't use any built-in string functions for this problem.

This is what I have so far:

```
userString = str(input("Please enter a string:"))
numVowels = 0
n=0
a=0
e=0
i=0
o=0
u=0
y=0


while (ord(userString[n]) != 0 or ord(userString[n+1])!=0):

   if (userString[n] == 'a' or userString[n]=='A'):
       a += 1
       numVowels += 1
   elif (userString[n] == 'e' or userString[n]=='E'):
       e += 1
       numVowels += 1
   elif (userString[n] == 'i' or userString[n]=='I'):
       i += 1
       numVowels += 1
   elif (userString[n] == 'o' or userString[n]=='O'):
       o += 1
       numVowels += 1
   elif (userString[n] == 'u' or userString[n]=='U'):
       u += 1
       numVowels += 1 
   elif (userString[n] == 'y' or userString[n]=='Y'):
       y += 1
       numVowels += 1
   n+=1

print("There are", numVowels, "vowels. There are", a, "A's", e, "E's", i,  "I's", o, "O's", u, "U's, and", y, "Y's, including both uppercase and lowercase versions.")
```

However I keep getting the error:

```
IndexError: string index out of range
```

I am using Python 3.

Answer (score 2):

First, you don't need to look at `userString[n+1]`. Trying to do so when `n` is already the last index is the first thing that triggers that error message.

Second, even if you remove that test, your loop will still not terminate when it should, because the `nul` character it's looking for at the end of the string is an implementation detail in the runtime of the C code that comprises the Python interpreter. From Python itself, that character is inaccessible, so `ord(userString[n])` will never be 0 for any `n` unless you explicitly put a `"\0"` in the string at the Python level. Failing that, the loop will sail past the end of the string and trigger the same `IndexError` when you try to access `userString[n]` with `n` equal to the length of the string.

There are better ways to loop through a string in Python, but the simplest fix for your code is to change the `while` condition to this:

```
while n < len(userString):
```

If `len` counts as a "built-in string function", which is debatable, then you should just loop over the string in a more typical Pythonic way:

```
for ch in userString: 
  if (ch == 'a' or ch=='A'):
    a += 1
    numVowels += 1
  ...
```

There are improvements that can be made to the conditional code that checks for vowels as well (as in mbaytas's answer), but that wasn't your question.

Comment: is len(string) a built in string function?

Comment: It's a built-in global function, not restricted to strings; it also works on lists and tuples.

Answer (score 1):

In Python, you can iterate over a string, like you would over a list.

Exploiting this functionality, and using a list to store the vowels, you can use something along the lines of the following code to achieve the functionality you want:

```
inputString = "This is our input string."

vowels = ["A", "E", "I", "O", "U", "Y", "a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "y"]

vowelCount = 0
for character in inputString:
  if (character in vowels):
    vowelCount += 1

print vowelCount
```

I see that your code in the question makes use of conditionals and loops, but not lists. If you'd like to avoid using lists for some reason (e.g. not covered in class yet), you can do the following:

```
inputString = "This is our input string."

vowelCount = 0
for character in inputString:
  if (character == 'A' or
      character == 'E' or
      character == 'I' or
      character == 'O' or
      character == 'U' or
      character == 'Y' or
      character == 'a' or
      character == 'e' or
      character == 'i' or
      character == 'o' or
      character == 'u' or
      character == 'y'):
    vowelCount += 1

print vowelCount
```

You can also modify the code above using `elif` statements instead of `or` logic to break down the occurrence of each vowel.

If you'd like to avoid using the `for ... in ...` functionality and stick to the `while` loop, consider the following:

```
vowelCount = 0
index = 0
while (index < len(inputString)):
  if (inputString[index] in vowels):
    vowelCount += 1
  index += 1
```

Comment: Personally, I would `lower(character)`

Answer (score 1):

Python offers many features that make solving problems like this a joy. Dictionary comprehensions, list comprehensions, etc.:

```
vowels = {v: 1 for v in 'aeiouyAEIOUY'}

def num_vowels(input_string):
    return sum(vowels.get(character, 0) for character in input_string)

print(num_vowels(str(input("Please enter a string:")))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's always a good approach to implement the general case first and derive your special case from that. I assumed that you can are "allowed" to use a `dict`. I avoided built-in methods of `str` for this.

```
def count_chars(s, chars):
    cdict = {i:0 for i in chars}
    for c in s:
        try:
            cdict[c] += 1
        except KeyError:
            pass
    return cdict

def count_vowels(s):
    chars = ['a','e','i','o','u', 'y', 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U', 'Y']
    vowels = count_chars(s, chars=chars)
    return vowels, sum(vowels.values())

# test it
tally, total = count_vowels(str(input()))
print(tally, total)
```

Answer (score 0):

I will give it a try too :)
code below individual vowel and sum that up for total vowels count

```
input_string = str(input("Please enter a string: "))

vowel = [['a','A'], ['e','E'], ['i','I'], ['o','O'], ['u','U'], ['y','Y']]
vc = [0] * 6 # individual vowel count

for ch in input_string:
    for i,v in enumerate(vowel):
        if ch in v:
            vc[i] += 1

total = sum(vc)

print("There are", total, "vowels.")
print("There are {0} A's {1} E's {2} I's {3} O's {4} U's, and {5} Y's, including both uppercase and lowercase versions.".format(*vc))
```

Comment: You could `lower()` the input string, and only check lowercase letters

Comment: @cricket_007, i know can use lower function, i just wanna fullfill the question rule that CAN'T USE any built in string function. If not i would have just use the string count method to done the job easier 

Comment: What are we considering string functions? Isn't `__iter__` the string function that allows `for c in input_string`?

Comment: Good point @cricket_007, if thats the case, then none of the answer here so far is pass then. Maybe you can show us better solution 